# MS Access shows #deleted, although data is saved correctly

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

We have an MS Access 2007 database with a MS SQL Server 2008 backend.

On the server, for each table, we have written a view, and each view contains triggers for update/insert/delete. These views are then linked into MS Access as linked tables.

Every server table contains a primary key consisting of one or more columns, plus a separate IDENTITY column (int, with unique index).

Now, if I go into MS Access and enter data directly into the linked table, everything works fine.

But if I create a **Form**, which uses the linked table as recordsource, then after each insert, all fields show **#deleted**. However, the data is stored correctly into the database, so it is mainly a display problem!

I think this has something to do with the triggers, but I cannot find the problem.

Can anyone help on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was actually a problem in the trigger, which caused more than row to get updated or inserted. After fixing the trigger, everything works now.